# Draw text and add to a UIImage iOS 5/6

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics, draw

I have a textbox, where i want the written text to be added to a UIImage.

How can i draw NSString to a UIImage?

I´ve searched, and found lots of examples, but non of them works. Xcode just gives me lots of errors.

Simply put, i want to draw a NSString to a UIimage. The UIImage should be the same size as a predefined UIImageView, and be placed in center.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think solution is here..i have used this method in one of my application
here lbltext is the object of my label. this method creates new image with given text & return the object of new image with text.

```
-(UIImage *) drawText:(NSString*) text inImage:(UIImage*)image atPoint:(CGPoint)point 
{
    UIFont *font = lblText.font;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(iv.frame.size);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,iv.frame.size.width,iv.frame.size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x,point.y,lblText.frame.size.width, lblText.frame.size.height);
    [lblText.textColor set];
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font]; 
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

in your below comment you have passed iv.center as a point.. try manualy like this

```
CGPoint point;
point.x=30; // dynamicaly just for example lblText.frame.origin.x;
point.y=40; //lblText.frame.origin.y;
```

you have to call above method like this...

```
UIImage *img = [self drawText:@"Test String" inImage:originalImage atPoint:point];
```

here,img is another instace of UIImage for storing new image with text...after calling this method use img imager for your further use..

for example...

```
[newimageviewObj setImage:img];
```

i hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks, will try as soon as i get home :)

Comment: Cant get it to work. Guess im doing something wrong.

im doing: [self drawText:@"teest" inImage:testImage atPoint:iv.center];

testImage is an instance variable UIImage *testImage.
iv is my ImageView
and lblText is a UILabel in my view.

Comment: @EspenBirk i have edited my answer just check it out....tell me what you have got..

Comment: @P R J Now it works perfect! Thanks alot PRJ :D
I tried setting the CGPoint manually like you described, and was about to ask you how i can center it in my UIImageView, but then i saw you already written it. If i remove the manual CGPoint it will be in the center of my UIImageView.

Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

UIImage is not a subview of UIView, so you cant add a subview to it. Also NSString is not a subview of UIView. If you want to show things on the screen, they should inherit from UIView.

So try this:

Create a UIImageView - set its image property to be your UIImage instance.

Create a UILabel - set its text property to your NSString.

Add the UILabel as a subview of your UIImageView.

and finally add your UIImageView to your current view controllers view.

Comment: He asking about *drawing*, nothing prevents him from drawing some text onto created UIImage and then add it to UIImageView.

Comment: Of course, you're right, but I'll still keep the answer up since it provides a reasonable alternative.

Comment: I found a working code now. But it looks lika a low resolution image thats been scaled up. 

I tried to add a subview with a text, but i could not figure out how to add that subview into a uiimage

Answer (score 0):

Emm, here is some thoughts.
I think that one simple way is like this :

1. Put aUIImageView on aView;
2. Add aUITextView on aView;
3. Get ScreenShot from aView;

This may works fine.

Also, this may come with a problem that screenshot may be not clear.
Then, After step1 and step2, we may get new image by UIGraphics.
(With here, we already know position where text should be on image and this should be ok.)

PS: Some image may not have some attribution like CGImage and CGImage is needed for this. So, transform it.