# camera photos save in document folder with name and view in tableview in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to take photos by camera and save in document directory with name and images are veiw in UITableViewCell.

If i select any one row the corresponding row image will go to next view with name and image.

Please give your idea,suggestion, and ref code.

Comment: hi, are you want to store camera picture in local directory?

Comment: yes.. i want to save image in directory file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For take picture using camera:

```
   imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message: @"Camera is not available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

    }
```

Add this method also.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *data=UIImagePNGRepresentation(pickedImage);

    NSString *FileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"test1.png"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileName];
    [data writeToFile:tempPath atomically:YES];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Display directory image to UITablevieCell Just call this method :

```
 NSString *strPath= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test.png"];
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]; 
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strPath]; 
 NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]; 
 NSData *returnData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:targetURL]; 
 UIImage *imagemain=[UIImage returnData];
```

Comment: ya i'm showing you code how to load documnet directory image in tableview

Comment: How to add text data like, i want to describe image with two lines how to add image and text data in single file and save in tableveiw cell.

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda, you should add your code from the comment as an edit to your answer.

Comment: @user2841148 what do you actually want?

Comment: if you want to add text on UIImage than refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571852/draw-text-and-add-to-a-uiimage-ios-5-6

Comment: Actually my question is take photo by camera give name for that image and add some few lines for image description this are all save in document folder, the image and image name will be view in UITableview.  If i select any row in UITableview the correspondence row will go to next view with image and image description.

Comment: I did it nearly 80% in my answer. @user2841148

Comment: If you want to store image description in document folder than just write the same code used for store image just change the filename test.txt and take description in NSString and [strName writeToFile:tempPath atomically:YES];

Answer (score 2):

try this method to store UIImage in Local Directory  ...

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

 UIImage *pickedImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
 [self addImage:pickedImage toCacheWithIdentifier:@"NAME OF THE IMAGE"];

}

- (void)addImage:(UIImage *)image toCacheWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

    NSString *folderPath = @"LOCAL DIRECTORY PATH ";
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath isDirectory:nil]) {

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:folderPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
    }

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",identifier];

 fileName = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

   [imageData writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
}
```

to retrieve image onClicking the tableView cell call this method from `didselectRowAtIndexPath` ....

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromCacheWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier {

    NSString *folderPath = @"LOCAL DIRECTORY PATH ";

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",identifier];

    fileName = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    if([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName]) {

        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];

    }

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in your **.h** file.

Implement it's method

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *anImage = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anImage, 1.0);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *tmpPathToFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/specificImagedName.jpg", path];

    if([imageData writeToFile:tmpPathToFile atomically:YES])
    {
          //Write was successful. 
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    // Dismiss your UIImagePickerController
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Implement `UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource` in your **.h** file
Then implement

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell =[ tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UIImage * image;
    UILabel * Title;

    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]autorelease];

        Title     = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 14, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        [Title setTag:111];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:invoiceTitle];
        [Title release];

        image     = [[UIImage alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 0, 50, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];
        [image setTag:222];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:projectTitle];
        [image release];

    }
    else
    {

        Title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:111];
        image = (UIImage *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:222];
    }


    [image setText:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:YOUR_IMAGE_PATH]];

    [Title setText:YOUR_CONTACT_NAME];

    return cell;
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return NO_OF_SECTIONS;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    /* switch (section) // For different number of rows per section
    {
        case 0:
        {
            return NO_OF_ROWS_IN_SECTION;
            break;
        }

        case 1:
        {
            return NO_OF_ROWS_IN_SECTION;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }*/

    return NO_OF_ROWS;
}
```