# Need to apply gesture in label view at fix corner point like ZDStckerView in objective c in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to implement text on image with resizing feature like i can zoom text field or label in or out by clicking a corner point of label...and i want to save that text on  image view...

i refer sticker view ...but the label inside image does not zoom in or out...

code :
//add a label inside imageview

```
UILabel  *lb1 = [[UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,40)];
UIimageview *imgview_sign =  [[UIImageview alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,140)];

[imgview_sign addsubview:lbl1];
```

//add aZDSticker view

```
ZDStickerView *userResizableView = [[ZDStickerView alloc] initWithFrame:imgview_sign.frame];
userResizableView.tag = 0;
userResizableView.delegate = self;
userResizableView.contentView = imgview_sign;
userResizableView.preventsPositionOutsideSuperview = NO;
[userResizableView showEditingHandles];
[self.view addSubview:userResizableView];
```

//Imageview is zoomed properly in or out but my label is not zomming....i want to apply gesture on label also ...

Comment: @all i need to zoom in or out label view with gesture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to draw text on uiimage, this should work. 
Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578118/2298998

Comment: i want to apply zoom and rotate gesture on label also...

Comment: thanku your code helps me alot....thanku soo much...